# setup icon winform

Tags: winforms

I have setup file of winform. but i want to change my icon how to change please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using VS to make the setup file.

In the winforms application [ not the setup project ]

1. Right click and choose Properties of the Project.
2. In the section Application, under Resources you can choose the icon for the project. It should be a .ico file.